# Excessive updates to cache_container table

Tags: database

I am maintaining a large drupal instance (10 nodes). Recently I am facing an issue.

The website was up and running. But the database was overloaded, MySQL binary logs kept growing abnormally, majority was an UPDATE statement to `cache_container` table. It kept growing upto point which crashed the MySQL cluster. I was able to quickly identify and make the site up. The binary logs was still growing. I cleared the cache and it worked. No more UPDATE statement to `cache_container`.

I have to file with the regulator, what is the root cause. Till now, I am not able to find out the cause for the constant UPDATE statements to `cache_container` that caused the DB crash.

I am using Redis.

Comment: You might want to also look into the `watchdog` table.

Comment: @NoSssweat dblog module is disabled. I use syslog module to log it into a file. There was no clue on that from the logs.

Comment: Can you post the output of "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" in mysql specifically the queries to the cache_container. Maybe that gives hint on what is going on. You're using Redis but not as a cache backend?